# Citing a webpage

Tags: natbib

somehow i don't get the citation right. I viewed the internet for solutions but somehow can't get it right. Here is my latex file with used packages.

```
  \documentclass[english,12pt,oneside, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}   % need for figures
\usepackage{verbatim}   % useful for program listings
\usepackage{color}      % use if color is used in text
\usepackage{subfigure}  % use for side-by-side figures
\usepackage{hyperref}   % use for hypertext links, including those to external documents and URLs
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd,amsbsy,amsxtra}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{darpa16}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{auction}
\end{document}
```

And now my bibtex file

```
@ONLINE{darpa16,
author = {Cheryl Pellerino},
title = {Three Teams Earn Prizes in DARPA Cyber Grand Challenge},
year = {2016},
url = {https://www.defense.gov/News/Article/Article/906931/three-teams-earn-prizes-in-darpa-cyber-grand-challenge}
}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

The bibstyle `agsm` doesn't know the entry type `online`, which is already
reported by the bibtex run:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: zzz2.aux
The style file: agsm.bst
Database file #1: auction.bib
Warning--entry type for "darpa16" isn't style-file defined
--line 1 of file auction.bib
(There was 1 warning)
```

Instead of `natbib` and `bibtex` use the new `biblatex` with `biber`:

```
[...]
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{auction.bib}

\begin{document}
 \parencite{darpa16}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]